# ¿Cómo puedo modificar esta función con FOR para que funcione con el ciclo repetitivo WHILE? en python

Tags: python

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito adaotar la funcion para no utilizar el modulador for sino el ciclo While y tener los mismos resultados, conocer los divisores de un número

Comment: por favor coloca el codigo como texto :)

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow, te invito a hacer el [tour]. Por favor, [no publiques imágenes con código fuente](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2869/21), copia y pega directamente el código en tu pregunta. NO olvides incluir de la misma manera mensajes exactos de error. Si los pantallazos son malos, ¡las fotos son aún peores! Un saludo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sinceramente no hay mucha ciencia a tras de esto, pues es tan fácil como cambiar el `for` por un `while` y definir `i=1` arriba del `while`.

```py
    ...
    else:
        ...
        i = 1
        while i in range(1,numero+1):#iteramos segun la condicion
            if numero%i == 0: #comprobamos
                print(i,end=" ") #imprimimos
            i+=1 #sumamos 1 a la variable 1
```

En cada iteración del ciclo `for` se suma 1 a la variable de control pues es igual que `for(i=0; i<lenght(array); i++)` en otros lenguajes, solo que en Python tiene una sintaxis mas reducida y flexible :).

Como extra, si quieres hallar la suma de los divisores puedes hacerlo de 2 maneras, yo te mostrare una, que es almacenar la variable `i` en una lista encaso se cumpla la condición `numero%i==0` y luego sumamos la lista

```py
    ...
    else:
        ...
        i = 1
        divisores = []#aqui se almacenara los divisores
        while i in range(1,numero+1):
            if numero%i == 0:
                divisores.append(i)#si se cumple almacenos la variable i
                print(i,end=" ")
            i+=1  

        #una vez termine el ciclo imprimimos
        print(f"la suma de divisores es: {sum(divisores)}")
```

La función `sum()` recibe como parámetro un iterable (lista) y suma sus elementos.

Comment: Y si también quiero sumar los valores de los divisores ¿Cómo quedaría?

Comment: guardalos en una variable y sumas en cada iteracion

Comment: Me podría mostrar cómo, lo siento mucho

Comment: ok, ahora edito la respuesta

Comment: Muchas gracias, de verdad

Comment: Listo, ya la edite